# Import a python class of non packaged module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Given a .py file in `/absolute/path/file.py` which contains a class `MyClass` which is not packaged [i.e. can't use import_module(x.y.z)],

how can I import that class dynamically from another .py file in Python3.X? It's important that it's done dynamically cause the name and path of the class to import will be different according to some parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `importlib` to import your module and `inspect` to find the class by name in imported module

```
import importlib.util
import inspect

absolute_path = '/absolute/path/file.py'
file_name = 'file.py'
class_name = 'Class'

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(file_name, absolute_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

cls = None
for member in inspect.getmembers(module):
    if member[0] == class_name:
        cls = member[1]

instance = cls()
print(instance)
# <file.py.Class object at 0x7f3e002c0000>
```

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work with `threading.Thread(target=spec.loader.exec_module, args=[module])`? (The for loop fails to find class_name)