# Import a python class of non packaged module, and run in it's own thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

[This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54851840/8425667) details how to use importlib to import a module, and inspect to find the contained class by name.

While this works when using `spec.loader.exec_module(module)` to execute the module, 'MyClass' cannot be found in `module` when running exactly the same code in a thread, like so: `threading.Thread(target=spec.loader.exec_module, args=[module])`

I have set up a working example that can be run to see this effect demonstrated in a simple way, simply copy the following into two files and execute the first one.

File 1:

```
# test1.py

import importlib.util
import inspect
import threading

my_file = 'thread_test'
path = "thread_test.py"

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(my_file, path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)

# Comment out one of the following snippets to test each version:

# OPTION 1:
# Non-Threaded Version, Works:
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

# OPTION 2:
# Threaded Version, Doesn't work (Causes cls to not be found in the following loop):
# thread = threading.Thread(target=spec.loader.exec_module, args=[module])
# thread.start()

cls = None
for member in inspect.getmembers(module):
    if member[0] == 'MyClass':
        cls = member[1]

cls.color = 'blue'

cls().PrintColor()
```

File 2:

```
# thread_test.py

class MyClass:
    color = None
    
    def PrintColor(self):
        print(self.color)
```

Why doesn't the module contain MyClass when executed in it's own thread, yet it it does then executed in the same thread?

Comment: You should include what "doesn't work" mean in your question.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed that. Another option is to replace the for loop with `cls = getattr(module, 'MyClass')`, which throws a more useful error for Option 2: "AttributeError: module 'thread_test' has no attribute 'MyClass'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing with others I have come to the following solution.
**The problem can be solved by running the loading of the module and class in it's own thread**. Essentially just starting the thread sooner.

So we put it all into the following function like so:

```
# Run this in it's own thread
def my_function(module, class_name):
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    
    # Get class
    for member in inspect.getmembers(module):
        if member[0] == class_name:
            my_class = member[1]
        if my_class is None:
            my_print("Error: Could not find class " + class_name + '!')
            return

    # Set properties
    my_class.color = 'blue'
    
    # Execute code
    cls().PrintColor()
```

Import:

```
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(file, path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
```

Then simply execute this function in it's own thread:

```
# Start thread
thread = threading.Thread(target=my_function, args=[module, class_name])
thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only started the Thread, but you have to join it and wait until it has run: `thread.join()`. Otherwise the module wont be imported correctly.

Full example:

```
import importlib.util
import inspect
import threading

my_file = 'thread_test'
path = "thread_test.py"

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(my_file, path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)

# Comment out one of the following snippets to test each version:

# OPTION 1:
# Non-Threaded Version, Works:
# spec.loader.exec_module(module)

# OPTION 2:
# Threaded Version, Doesn't work (Causes cls to not be found in the following loop):
thread = threading.Thread(target=spec.loader.exec_module, args=[module])
thread.start()
thread.join()

cls = None
for member in inspect.getmembers(module):
    if member[0] == 'MyClass':
        cls = member[1]

cls.color = 'blue'

cls().PrintColor()
```

Result:

`blue`

Comment: Whilst this technically works, the problem is that thread.join() blocks the main thread, and so negates the benefit of starting a thread in the first place for most applications.